# How do I capture a specific AJAX (XHR) event in the Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, post

I'm trying to scrape some information from the United States Postal Service's Every Door Direct Mail service. The service is straightforward. On [the USPS EDDM website](https://eddm.usps.com/eddm/customer/routeSearch.action), a user enters a ZIP code, e.g. 10030, clicks the search button, and that displays a map. **That call is easy to capture in a browser developer console**. That's just a GET request like this:

```
https://gis.usps.com/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/routes/execute?f=json&env:outSR=102100&ZIP=10030&Rte_Box=R&UserName=EDDM
```

The problem, though, is trying to capture the table or the textual information displayed on the right of the page. The "Show Table" option:

[image]

displays output like this, at which point you can click "Select All (10 routes)" and it will show you something like on the right side of the page:

[image]

**How do I capture this set of Javascript "button-click" requests?** For now I'm just trying to capture these requests so I can replicate them programmatically (in Python, but that's not strictly relevant here).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to make two GET requests to get all of the data. The second request is necessary to obtain the total number of PO Boxes.  Perhaps they can be combined into one, I didn't dig into it too much.

1. `https://gis.usps.com/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/routes/execute?f=json&env%3AoutSR=102100&ZIP=10030&Rte_Box=R&UserName=EDDM`
2. `https://gis.usps.com/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/boxes/execute?f=json&env%3AoutSR=102100&ZIP=10030&Rte_Box=B&UserName=EDDM&extent=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-15628202.596646052%2C%22ymin%22%3A749662.6717286934%2C%22xmax%22%3A-6235620.560966092%2C%22ymax%22%3A7070087.666571667%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%7D`

I know you're working in Python but since you're playing in Chrome DevTools, here's a JavaScript example of how to obtain the total number of delivery addresses:

```
let promises = [
    fetch('https://gis.usps.com/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/routes/execute?f=json&env%3AoutSR=102100&ZIP=10030&Rte_Box=R&UserName=EDDM'),
    fetch('https://gis.usps.com/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/boxes/execute?f=json&env%3AoutSR=102100&ZIP=10030&Rte_Box=B&UserName=EDDM&extent=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-15628202.596646052%2C%22ymin%22%3A749662.6717286934%2C%22xmax%22%3A-6235620.560966092%2C%22ymax%22%3A7070087.666571667%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%7D')
];

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(async res => {
        if (res[0].ok && res[1].ok) {
            const first = await res[0].json();
            const second = await res[1].json();

            const results = [...first.results[0].value.features, ...second.results[0].value.features];
            
            console.log("Total Residential Addresses:", results.reduce((acc, row) => acc + row.attributes.RES_CNT, 0));
            console.log("Total Business Addresses:", results.reduce((acc, row) => acc + row.attributes.BUS_CNT, 0));
            console.log("Total Delivery Addresses:", results.reduce((acc, row) => acc + row.attributes.TOT_CNT, 0));
        }
    });
```

Updated to show how to retrieve residential and business addresses separately.

Comment: Thanks for this. How did you figure out the second GET request? I'll have to modify it because I'm not just looking for the total number of PO boxes, but rather the total number of residential and/or business addresses and the other data in the table.

Presumably when I do this in Python I'd have to make both GET requests in the same session? Does the second rely on the first somehow?

Comment: If you watch the requests in the XHR tab of the Network panel you'll see both requests one after the other.  The two requests don't rely upon each other, one points to .../GPServer/routes and the other to ../GPServer/boxes.  All of the data in that table is in the responses from those two calls in results[0].value.features.attributes property.  It looks like BUS_CNT is businesses and RES_CNT is for residential.